# Splash screen in JWS

Tags: java, splash-screen, java-web-start

I have java web start application which loads very slow. When I run it, first I see just splash screen, then splash screen disappear and I have to wait for loading my application. That is the moment when splash screen disappear and application doesn't  run yet and I do not know if application is loading (because everything process in background). So my question is -> do I have any opportunity extend time of availability of splash screen or just run some information like label/frame/window instead of splash screen which will inform user application is loading and no need to start app again but just wait? Can I do that in jnlp? Or separated lauch file, which is independent from my app? I do not want modify my app